# How to access options object after it's composited/used to create a ClientRequest

Tags: http, node.js

Skimming through the nodejs docs I see *options* objects being passed to configure features in the `http` library.  However I don't see a quick way to access the original *options* that were used in a [http.request(options, callback)](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) call to construct a `http.ClientRequest` object, after the fact.  Are original options available through the request object and not deemed private, or should I instead hold my own reference to the original options in case I want to use them later?

I assume the options are composited inside the http.ClientRequest object, but that could be wrong.

I could probably try going either way with this (dig into composited info, or pass around an external reference to it), but am new enough to nodejs that I want some sage advice first, to find out what I *should* do if the option object's available, and by using best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always keep your own reference. Most of the time you have no way of telling what's going to happen to that object after you pass it to a constructor. Almost everybody leaves it alone, but some libraries/modules may have side-effects on it. For example, you may see source code doing:

```
options.foo = options.foo || 'bar';
```

...modifying your object. So you may even have to clone your object before passing it to a constructor if you want to keep a reference to it.

As for `ClientRequest` in particular, it doesn't hold a public reference to the options object, but it has properties that match some of the options like `req.path` or `req.port`.